# Connecting to Nike+ RestAPI through cURL

Tags: curl, nikeplus-api

I'm trying to access my Nike+ data using curl. I can get a valid Token from Nike+ with the following curl invoke:

```
curl -k 'https://developer.nike.com/services/login' --data-urlencode username='<MYEMAIL>' --data-urlencode password='<MYPASSWORD>'
```

The response with the temporary token looks something like:

```
{"access_token":"FNPGS0sKhmZowCFiyV2w4GlKywDK","expires_in":"3599","profile_img_
url":"","token_type":"bearer"}
```

I've then tried to curl with the token:

```
curl -k -X GET 'https://api.nike.com/v1/m
e/sport/activities' --data-urlencode access_token='FNPGS0sKhmZowCFiyV2w4GlKywDK'
```

Which results in the error response :

```
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid Access Token","detail":{"errorcode":"keymanagem
ent.service.invalid_access_token"}}}
```

Did anybody already do this/get this running?

Cheers,
Mihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the request url should have been different. Now working with:

```
curl -k -X GET https://api.nike.com/v1/me/sport/activities?access_token=FNPGS0sKhmZowCFiyV2w4GlKywDK
```

Comment: HI Mihai, just wanted to ask you if you get more than 5 results with the above curl command? For me it just shows me the data for my last 5 runs.

Comment: Do you know how to get the rest?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. Is it not specified in the documentation ? I was only interested in the last run..

Comment: Yes sorry. There's a "count" parameter which allows you to get the specified number of runs.